# See when a tag was first added

Tags: tags

Does anyone know how to determine the time/data when a tag was added to the site?

Is this even kept in the database?

Comment: This information is not stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is not stored but you may tweak it to fit your need.

Refer: [How to add a date creation field when a custom taxonomy relationship is created?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138297/how-to-add-a-date-creation-field-when-a-custom-taxonomy-relationship-is-created)

Comment: Seems fairly involved, thanks. I think I will look at options or getting a developer involved.